# android with cordova and authobahnJS

Tags: android, cordova

I need to implement WAMPv2 in an android application to be able to connect to a python server which uses WAMPv2.

I went to the autobahn website to try to get an WAMPv2 lib for android, but their lib only supports WAMPv1, so it does not work for me. I tried with JAWAMPA and was able to connect, but the lib does not have any CRA, which I need, so it does not work for me either.

Now I am trying to run Android with Cordova and then run AutobahnJS on it, which supports everything I need. The issue I am having now is the error: `E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/autobahn/autobahn.js:15`. The JS I am using are those:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/autobahn/autobahn.js"></script>
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Is it possible at all to run AutobahnJS on Android?

Edit:

I got around the error by using a minified version of autobahnJS now when I try to connect I get "unsupported" as a reason onclose on the connection. Is it possible to run autobahnJS on android at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual Problem might be. I need more information. Which port is the server listening to?

Comment: The port is 8080, when I run the same script on an local Apache it connects and outputs something different then "unsupported".